# vSphere 4 - how can I cancel a file copy in progress?

Tags: vmware-vsphere

VMware vSphere 4
SAN storage with multiple data-stores
No vCenter

I shut-down a virtual machine and using the data-store browser did a copy/paste to copy the VM to a new datastore with additional space.  The file copy performance was very poor, and due to time constraints I decided to cancel the copy task.  However the copy task showing in the vsphere client can not be cancelled; the cancel option is disabled.

Currently I am not able to start the machine in it's original location as the disk files are locked for the copy.  How can I abort the copy?  I tried deleting the target directory but this did not abort the copy task.

Comment: Did you try to connect on the ESX(i) directly and kill the process with 15 signal or worst case scenario 9 ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to cancel the copy by creating a dummy virtual machine with a disk almost big enough  to fill the datastore; shortly after the copy process caused the space to run out and cancelled itself.

If someone has a better solution I'll accept that as the answer, because that seems like a horrible way to stop a file copy and I'd like to know how to do it nicely.

Comment: I equate this to "I had to slow down my bike so I used a stick in the spokes". Beware the potential problems.

Comment: Please do not mark this answer as correct. This is a very bad way to make your ESX(i) cancel the task. It does have impact on all your servers.

Answer (score 10):

The answer depends on the version of vSphere you've got.

**Step 1:First make sure you disable the automatic restart of VM's.**

[image]

**Step 2: enable the SSH console**

From: http://kb.vmware.com/selfservice/microsites/search.do?language=en_US&cmd=displayKC&externalId=8375637

> To create a user in ESX host for using a SSH client:
>
> ```
> Log in to the vSphere Client as a root user.
> Click Users & Groups.
> Right-click on a blank area and click Add.
> Enter a username and password. Confirm your password.
>
> Note: Starting in ESX 4.0, the password needs to be at least 
> 8 characters in length.
>
> Select Grant shell access to this user and click OK.
> ```

**Step 3: log into ssh**
Download putty from: http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/download.html

**Step 3a (ESX only) Restart the VM client daemon**

```
service mgmt-vmware restart
```

**Step 3b (Esxi only) Restart the VM client daemon**

```
/etc/init.d/hostd restart
```

**Step 4 Wait for the vSphere client to reconnect**
All of your VM's will still be running as before, only the vSphere app will restart.
With it the copy process will stop.

**Bonus: a better way to copy**

If you have thinly provisioned client, you can use the command-line tool `vmkfstools` like so:

`vmkfstools -i /vmfs/volumes/path_to_datastore/path_to_source_vm/vmname.vmdk /vmfs/volumes/path_to_dest_datastore/path_to_dest_vm/vmname.vmdk -d thin &`

This will clone (`-i`) the vmdk file and make sure the destination file is thinly (`-d thin`) provisioned. The `&` at the end of the command will make sure you get your command prompt back.

It will copy much faster than the GUI copy does, and you can cancel it easier.

**canceling a vmkfstools copy**

`ps |grep vmkfstools`
Note down the PID.
`kill 12345`
Where 12345 is the first number listed on the vmkfstools line.

Comment: thanks, I just needed the last part to make sure I could safely kill the `vmkstools` copy correctly. for me, this command line was slow and failed.

Comment: This one solved my issue!